# Multi select list excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a couple of lists within an excel spreadsheet that I would like to add the multi-select option to. I am well aware of how to do this thanks to [contexture](http://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
'      NOTE: you can use a line break,
'      instead of a comma
'      Target.Value = oldVal _
'        & Chr(10) & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that I only want particular lists to be multi-select, i have a couple of other lists within this excel spreadsheet that must remain as one option lists. This code works but it affects every list within excel. I attempted to modify it to work on only certain Cells by adding an if statement like below

```
 If Target.Address = "$C$5" Or Target.Address = "$C$6" Or Target.Address = "$C$82" Then
```

This still is not working for me, how can I make this code cell specific?

Comment: Just change `Set rngDV` to whatever the cells that you want to be multi-select are. e.g. `Set rngDV = Union(Range("C5"), Range("C6"), Range("C82"),.....and so on)` And get rid of the `Else` statement you don't need them. Just use the `Not` statement in your `Ifs`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this in hopes of finding an answer on how to make a specific list have the multi-select option I was able to figure it out on my own.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strVal As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim Ar As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Dim lType As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo ExitHandler

lType = Target.Validation.Type
If lType = 3 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    If Target.Value = "Select all that apply" Then
    oldVal = ""
    Else
    If Target.Value = newVal Then
        newVal = "Select all that apply"
    Else
        oldVal = Target.Value
    End If
    End If
    'oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    'This is where specific cells will be referenced
        If Target.Address = "$F$8" Or Target.Address = "$G$6" Or Target.Address = "$H$3" Or Target.Address = "$CJ$29" Then
            If oldVal = "" Then
            Else
                If newVal = "" Then
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Ar = Split(oldVal, ", ")
                    strVal = ""
                    For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                        Debug.Print strVal
                        Debug.Print CStr(Ar(i))
                        If newVal = CStr(Ar(i)) Then
                            strVal = strVal
                            lCount = 1
                        Else
                            strVal = strVal & CStr(Ar(i)) & ", "
                        End If
                    Next i
                    If lCount > 0 Then
                        Target.Value = Left(strVal, Len(strVal) - 2)
                    Else
                        Target.Value = strVal & newVal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

In order to use this specific solution you will also need to add

```
ExitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To the very end of your code.